# Github pull request deleted other files

Tags: html, github

I'm fully beginner at programming. My homework at school is to make a webpage in groups. I was ready with my branch and i wanted to pull request it into the master where were other files made by my classmates. Then it was merged and all the other files were deleted. I reverted it, but how can we merge it without deleting the other files?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to first do

1. Do a `git pull` from the main branch to get the latest code of your classmates.
2. Spend sometime resolving any merge conflicts you may have.
3. Try again to re-push your code and submit the pull request.